# How do I mock a function that is called inside the function I am testing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

I have a register function which saves my user to the mongoose DB. When testing, I don't want the user to actually get saved to the DB so I want to override the mongoose save method.

My register method is as so:

```
async register({firstName, lastName, email, password}){
    try {
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
        const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

        return await new UserModel({
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            hash
        }).save()

    }catch (err) {
        console.log(`Unable to register new user: ${err}`)
        throw 'Unable to register new user'
    }
}
```

So I want to test this method. I have written the test but I don't know how I pass the mocked function into my `register()` function

```
import UserConnector from './user'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import UserModel from '../../models/user'

describe("User connector", () => {

    it("should register user", () => {

        const expectedUser = {
            firstName: "adsfja",
            lastName: "adsfja",
            email: "adsfja@alsda.com",
            password: "password123"
        }

        var myStub = sinon.stub(UserModel.prototype, 'save').withArgs(expectedUser) // <--- How can I pass this into my userConnector.register() method so that the stub is called instead of the real thing

        const user = new UserConnector().register(expectedUser)

        expect(user).toEqual({
            firstName: "adsfja",
            lastName: "adsfja",
            email: "adsfja@alsda.com"
        })

    })
})
```

How can I tell my `register()` method to use the stubbed function instead of calling the actual mongoose DB?

Comment: I guess your function register shouldn't have the dependencies hardcoded, so, you can create a class / closure (or not and just pass proper data into the function) and inyect the dependencies in the constructor / closure function, in that way you can inyect your testing dependencies to use the stubbed function

Comment: try `var myStub = sinon.stub(UserModel.prototype, 'save').callsFake(() => expectedUser)` & let me know how you go :) also note that register is async, so might be good to use `const userConnector = new UserConnector();  const user = await userConnector.register(expectedUser)`

Comment: here try this https://gist.github.com/shierro/ce4a85d0fc3fc5a393f1cbde6ed9bfc2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.0.0/stubs/), the way to achieve this is using `callsFake`

See example below

```
import UserConnector from './user'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import UserModel from '../../models/user'

describe("User connector", () => {

    it("should register user", async () => {

        const expectedUser = {
            firstName: "adsfja",
            lastName: "adsfja",
            email: "adsfja@alsda.com",
            password: "password123"
        }

        var myStub = sinon
          .stub(UserModel.prototype, 'save')
          .callsFake(() => Promise.resolve(expectedUser))

        const userConnector = new UserConnector();
        // since register is used as async, we should expect it to return a promise
        const user = await userConnector.register(expectedUser)

        expect(user).toEqual({
            firstName: "adsfja",
            lastName: "adsfja",
            email: "adsfja@alsda.com"
        })
        myStub.restore() // don't forget to restore stubbed function

    })
})
```

Hope this helps